# mysql connection with sql developer

Tags: mysql

I try to create a mysql connection with sql developer on MAC.

I loaded the mysql driver.

[image]

I tried to create a connection

[image]

But I had the following error

Statut : échec -Echec du test : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: You have to take care of the JDBC driver has the right version for your mySQL version. The connector you choose can only handle mysql version 8 and not 5

Comment: Hello, I tried the version 5 driver and it changes nothing. Furthermore I have the following version of mysql :  admin$ type -a mysql 
mysql is /usr/local/mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysql   I also have Application/MAMP version installed

Comment: So you can connect to mySQL from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by re installing the last version of mysql with the correct driver. Furthermore I had to execute the following mysql command

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00';
```

Comment: This is something you should setup in your mysql config file